# R sequence in subset

Tags: r, plot, dataframe

I've got a data frame looking like this:

```
in    out
3234  1
124   1
323   0
532   1
```

Now I'd like to make a plot of `mean(subset(data, data$in < x)$out)`. 
I attempt to generate a sequence for plotting like this:

```
x <- seq(0, 10000, by=1)
y <- mean(subset(data, data$in < x)$out)
```

But the second line gives me a warning "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length" and `plot(x, y)` results in an error. Meanwhile, if I put a number instead of `x` it works. Can anyone point out what's the problem with such approach?

Comment: Try to be careful to dimensions. You are confusing vectors and scalar values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use function `sapply()` to calculate mean for each element of `x`. But first changed column name of `in` to `ins` because it gave me an error.

```
colnames(data)<-c("ins","out")
x <- seq(0, 10000, by=1)
y <- sapply(x,function(x) mean(subset(data, ins < x)$out))
plot(x,y)
```

[image]